# How to take polygon centroid in Postgis

Tags: postgis, polygon, centroids

I have table with column name,Latitude and Longitude.I want to update this with polygon name and its centroid latitude longitude.I know there is a function in postgis st_centroid(geometry). But I want to enter x value and Y value in a separate column.How can I do this?

Comment: You want to write x and y of the centroid into new columns/attributes?

Comment: Yes, I have latitude and longitude columns.But St_centroid returns lat long value in a single column

Answer (score 21):

Try:

```sql
UPDATE polygon_layer 
SET longitude=ST_X(ST_Centroid(geom)), Latitude=ST_Y(ST_Centroid(geom));
```